# How to hide a specfic tab at product detail page on page load

Tags: magento2, product-tab

How to set product page-information-tab-content needs to be hidden when page load. 
When i click title only need to be display content.

Please let me know how to set.

[image]

Comment: I did not want to remove fully, just i need show/hidden

Comment: if you can share a link if it's a live site it will be easy to give solution.

Comment: It's a default magento2 tab

Answer (score 0):

You can find this `class="data item content"` in inspect element and set inline css to `style="display:none"`

It will solve your issue.

Comment: If again i click title it doesn't hidden